# ¿Cómo calcular la mínima diferencia de tiempo de llegada que el primero en las carreras?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy realizando una consulta que trata de encontrar el Nombre del piloto que consiguió la mínima diferencia de tiempo de llegada como segundo clasificado con respecto el primero en las carreras de 2018.

Entiendo el problema, pero me resulta complicado pensar cómo puedo hacer la operación "la mínima diferencia de tiempo de llegada que el primero en las carreras de 2018"

```
SELECT
NOMBREPILOTO AS PILOTO,
FECHA,
TPOCARRERA AS RETRASO
FROM TCOMPITE
WHERE YEAR(FECHA)=2018 AND PUESTOLLEGADA = 2
GROUP BY PILOTO
HAVING ¿?
```

No consigo sacar qué poner ahí (O corregirme algo). ¿Qué pondríais vosotros/corregiríais? Gracias.

EDITO:
**Le he construido un enunciado:**
"Listad el nombre del piloto que consiguió la mínima diferencia de tiempo de llegada como segundo clasificado con respecto al primero en las carreras celebradas en la temporada 2018.".

En la **tabla TCOMPITE** TENGO:

FECHA,PUESTOLLEGADA,NUMAUTO,NOMBREPILOTO,EQUIPO,VUELTAS,TPOCARRERA,PUESTOPARRILLA,PUNTOSCARRERA.

Comment: Debes dar mas detalles, muestra la estructura de tus tablas, trata de poner un ejemplo con datos reales para que se te entienda mejor

Comment: Editado, perdona. @Japv

Comment: como se calcula la diferencia?

Answer (score 0):

Existe una funcion en mysql llamada **`TIMESTAMPDIFF`** , la cual nos ayuda a realizar la resta.

Esta función también nos permite obtener otros valores como hora, días, segundos, etc.

El primer parametro es el resultado devuelto en minutos pero se puede cambiar por YEAR, HOUR , etc.
**Ejemplo :** `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fechaInicial,fechaFinal);`

```
SELECT
NOMBREPILOTO AS PILOTO,
FECHA,
TPOCARRERA AS RETRASO
FROM TCOMPITE
WHERE YEAR(FECHA)=2018 AND PUESTOLLEGADA = 2
GROUP BY PILOTO
HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fechaInicial,fechaFinal);
```

**Te dejo en enlace del manual :** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html
Ahora te dejo a ti el resto, espero haberte servido de ayuda.